# jQuery won't work on appended element

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<fieldset>      
   <select>
      <option value="">Position</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" />
   <select>
      <option value="">Function</option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" class="buttonAnd" value="And" />
   <input type="button" class="buttonOr" value="Or" />
</fieldset>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    field_count = 0;

    $(".buttonAnd").click(function(){
        field_count++;
        $('fieldset').append(jQuery("<br />"));
        var new_field = jQuery("<input type=\"button\" />")
        new_field.attr("class","buttonAnd");
        new_field.attr("name","buttonAnd_"+field_count);
        new_field.attr("value","And_"+field_count);
        $('fieldset').append(new_field);
    });
});
```

Appending new button works only on original two buttons, but it doesn't work on newly generated buttons. Any idea how to solve this?

Tnx!

**Thanx Travis J! I've tried your solution and it works. Thanks to everyone else as well!**

Comment: make a pure JS function and call it from the html element

Comment: Add an ID to the button (ex: `button+counter`) and call it by ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5a9cq/)***

Use event delegation with [jQuery's `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This will allow your future elements to have the event delegated to them

```
field_count = 0;

$("body").on("click",".buttonAnd",function(){
    field_count++;
    $('fieldset').append(jQuery("<br />"));
    var new_field = jQuery("<input type=\"button\" />")
    new_field.attr("class","buttonAnd");
    new_field.attr("name","buttonAnd_"+field_count);
    new_field.attr("value","And_"+field_count);
    $('fieldset').append(new_field);
});
```

Comment: @lad_ruz - If this solution helped you and you use it, can you please mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark? Thanks

Comment: Read the edit in question. Sorry it took me so long to click on checkmark. :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [.on()](http://www.api.jquery.com/on/) because you create those new buttons "on the fly". So what you need is event delegation. 
Otherwise the script doesn't notice that there are new buttons

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUvL7/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    field_count = 0;

    $(".buttonAnd").on('click', function(){
        field_count++;
        $('fieldset').append(jQuery("<br />"));
        var new_field = jQuery("<input type=\"button\" />");
        new_field.attr("class","buttonAnd");
        new_field.attr("name","buttonAnd_"+field_count);
        new_field.attr("value","And_"+field_count);
        $('fieldset').append(new_field);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your question yourself - that's because the `.click()` event is assigned to the buttons that exist at the moment when the event is assigned. If you need it to work for newly generated buttons, too, then you have to assign the event to the new buttons after they're created, just take care not to assign it the second time to the original buttons.